Failing to Generate Firebase Cloud Messaging Token
I am implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging in my android app.
I had done setup refering the official documentation of Firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging
Previously it was working as excepted and token was being generated notification was coming. But from past two days I am facing  SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE issue and token is not being generated also topic is not getting subscribed.
Following is my setup for FCM:
build.gradle(Project level)
buildscript {

    dependencies {

        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}

build.gradle (app level)

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}


dependencies{
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.1.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

}

I have also added google-services.json file inside app module.
The entire setup was working before this issue .
Error I am encountering :
E/FirebaseMessaging: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Won't retry the operation.
E/FirebaseMessaging: Failed to sync topics. Won't retry sync. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
E/Token Details: Token generation failed
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Can anyone help me out with this ?
